# Windchill - Add Related object to part using REST API

Tags: ptc-windchill

I'm currently aware on how to create a Part and how to create a Document using the REST API. I'm currently on V11M30. **What I need to reproduce using the API** are the following steps:

1- Check out the part:
[image]

2- Create a new Document with attachments

[image]
[image]

3- Add the document to the part

[image]

Using the REST API **I know how to**:

1- Check out the part

`/ProdMgmt/Parts('WTPartID')/PTC.ProdMgmt.CheckOut`

2- Create the document

`/DocMgmt/Documents`

3- Check out the document

`/DocMgmt/Documents('WTDocumentID')/PTC.DocMgmt.CheckOut`

4- Upload content from local file or URL to the new document (Attachments/Primary content)

5- Check in the document

6- Check in the part

**What I don't know** is how to relate / associate the document to the part. This means that the document will be created, but it won't show up in the "**Related Objects**" [Image 3] section of the part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a WTPartDescribeLink have a look on:

```
/ProdMgmt/Documents('WTDocumentID')/Describes
```

with body

```
"Describes@odata.bind" : "Parts('WTPartID')"
```

Please refer to this helpful article :
https://www.ptc.com/en/support/article/CS285572

Comment: Thanks, we followed the article and it worked !